# How to navigate through views more than once in Xcode Mac Os App

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-data, swiftui

I am creating a little macOs app in Xcode. And i want to navigate through views more than one time. When I navigate through one view and click to go to another it doesn't work, here's the code:

```
'''
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [], animation: .default) private var postits: FetchedResults<Postit>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
            VStack {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CreatePostitView()) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                } 
                // for example if i navigate to this view and then navigate to the a 
                // postit view it doesn't work, or viceversa.
                
                ForEach(postits) {postit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: PostitView(title: postit.title! , 
                    content: postit.content!)) {
                        Text(postit.title!)
                    } // for example if i navigate to this view and then navigate to 
                      //the create postit view it doesn't work, or viceversa.

                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.yellow .opacity(0.3))
                    .shadow(color: Color.yellow, radius: 10)
                    .padding(16)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    
    '''
```

Here is the postit view structure in case you need it

```
'''
struct CreatePostitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Creaate postit view")
    }
}
'''
```

And here is the postit detail view in case you need it too

```
'''
struct PostitView: View {
    
    let title : String
    let content : String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .padding()
        
        Text(content)
            .font(.title2)
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add everything you want in the sidebar inside a `List`

```
NavigationView {
    List {
        NavigationLink(destination: CreatePostitView()) {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }

        ForEach(postits) {postit in
            NavigationLink(destination: PostitView(title: postit.title ,
                                                   content: postit.content)) {
                Text(postit.title)
            }

        }
    }
    .listStyle(.sidebar)
}
```

(I removed some UI code for brevity)

Comment: thanks bro u resolved my problem!